# How to increment a Range object with a Loop

Tags: vba, excel

In this code I'm trying to increment two Range object's using .OffSet(1, 0).Activate.

```
  Function Foundry_check_func(target_cell As Range, result_cell As Range)
    For x = 1 To 20
        If result_cell <= 5 Then
            target_cell = "Value 1"
        ElseIf result_cell >= 10 Then
            target_cell = "Value 2"
        Else: target_cell = "Value 3"
        End If

        With target_cell
        .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End With

        target_cell.Offset(3, 0).Activate
        result_cell.Offset(4, 0).Activate
        Debug.Print ("Value: " & result_cell & " Loop: " & x)
    Next x


    ' Don't forget to format target cell at end of loop

End Function


Sub Foundry_check()
    Main = Foundry_check_func(Range("J22"), Range("K22"))
End Sub
```

However, I can see using Debug.Print that after each loop, the cell being read does not change. Here's the output:

```
Value: 1 Loop: 1
Value: 1 Loop: 2
Value: 1 Loop: 3
Value: 1 Loop: 4
Value: 1 Loop: 5
etc.
```

I've made a similar macro work using ActiveCell instead of a Range. But in this program I need to OffSet two sets of cells. One to read data (result_cell) and another to write a value based on that data (target_cell). I'm not sure how I could use ActiveCell to offset two different cells in the same loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need either `Offset` *or* `Activate`.  Just use the `Cells` collection directly. What exactly is this supposed to do?  The `Offsets` of 3 and 4 are going to increase the gap between your 2 ranges the longer the loop runs.

Comment: try: `set targetcell = targetcell.offset(3,0)` and `set resultcell = resultcell.offset(4,0)` instead of trying to activate the cell. your current code does activate the cell, but thats about it. target and result cell dont change

Comment: For this to be a successful `for` loop you need to use the iterator (`x`) to actually update something, or for something to incrementally change and update in the loop. Neither of which exist.

Comment: @NickSlash that did it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue that I see...

Your value isn't changing because you're target_cell isn't changing... you should add

```
  target_cell.address
```

to your debug script and you will see it's not changing...
To change the target cell you need to set the target_cell you can't just activate another... so you would do this:

```
    set target_cell = target_cell.Offset(3, 0)
    set result_cell = result_cell.Offset(4, 0)
```